# Why Tensorflow complains when shape is specified with round bracket but do not when it is specified with square bracket?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I specify `tf.random_normal([1])`, it works fine but when I specify `tf.random_normal((1))`, I get

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'random_normal_24/RandomStandardNormal' (op: 'RandomStandardNormal') with input shapes: [].
```

This behavior applies to many functions that requires shape to be inputed in Tensorflow.

Is this normal? Or is it a bug? Many tutorials and books use round bracket but it seems to be that square bracket should be the right way based on the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In python, a tuple with a single element is a scalar. Hence `(1) == 1`.

If you want to explicitly create a tuple that contains a single element, you have to use the syntax: `(1,)`.

Instead, in python, you can create a list with a single element using the square brackets: `[1] != 1`.

However, when you define shapes, you should prefer the usage of the tuple instead of the list, because in python the creation of a tuple is way more efficient than the creation of an array (a tuple is an immutable object while a list is not. Hence the python interpreter can do **a lot** of optimizations like constant folding, and moving the object around, while the list have to be copied).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a TensorFlow-specific issue. In Python, `(1)` is the same as `1`. You need an ugly syntax `(1,)` to specify an one-element tuple.

Comment: In that case, does it mean that it is better to just use square bracket to specify shape? Any caveats?

Comment: I don't know any difference from list and tuple for shapes in TF.